# Sound when typing or using mouse

Tags: sound, updates

Since the last update on Ubuntu 16.04. when typing or using the mouse I hear a noise through my speakers, low volume but very annoying.

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not have an answer. I would like to add that I also noticed the same issue on 16.04, not during normal operation, but during booting and shutting down.

Comment: is there a way to rollback the update that caused this problem